# How to map int into enum with EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Is there anyway to map int field into enum in EFv1? Thanks! I want my entity to have enum field rather than int field.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create two properties. One mapped to EF, one as a wrapper

```
[EdmScalarProperty]
public int EnumPropInteger {get;set}
public MyEnum EnumProp
{
    get { return (MyEnum) EnumPropInteger; }
    set { EnumPropInteger = (int)value; }
}
```

Not a nice way because you have two public properties but a way.

Comment: You can set the int property to be private, internal, or protected.

Comment: And EF can access then this Property?

Comment: @Arthur: Can you explain the purpose of the `[EdmScalarProperty]` attribute? I looked it up, but don't really see what it adds here.

Comment: @Jonathan Wood: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.dataclasses.edmscalarpropertyattribute(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: @Arthur: Thanks but I did see that reference and am still not clear on exactly what difference it makes. Can you say anything about what is different if you take that attribute away?

Answer (score 2):

It's supported with the new release : Now supported : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/06/30/announcing-the-microsoft-entity-framework-june-2011-ctp.aspx

Answer (score -3):

You can simply cast the int to the Enum like this:

```
public enum TestEnum
{
Zero = 0,
One,
Two
}

TestEnum target = (TestEnum)1;
```

Target should then contain TestEnum.One;

Edit: My bad, did not interpret properly at first. You want the map to handle the cast for you, right? Don't know that right now, would have to experiment a bit.